# How to align Chips vertically one after the other

Tags: android, material-design, android-xml, android-chips

[image]

How to align ChipGroup items vertically one after the other as shown in the image

```
 <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:chipSpacing="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            app:singleSelection="false"
            app:singleLine="false"
            app:flow_verticalAlign="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:flow_horizontalAlign="center"
            android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
            android:gravity="center">
```

Comment: Have you used LiearLayout for your case

Comment: @shohruh Maxmudov I am setting chips dynamically, so it is not possible to use linearlayout